# How to calculate the total number of combinations of dependent variables with non-uniform distribution?

Tags: combinatorics

How to calculate the total number of combinations of dependent variables with non-uniform distribution? 
for example, if I have 3 variable A, B, and C; each of them can have N different discrete states and with some correlation < 1. I have the probability distribution of each variable too. How can I calculate the exact number of combinations they can generate?  Thank you!

Comment: The number of possible states shouldn't depend on the correlation as long as the correlation is not $1$ or $-1.$ The probability distribution depends on the correlation, but the mere number of states does not.

Comment: Some combinations may never occur if there is a strong correlation. At least based on samples that we have. What do you think? @Michae

Answer (score 0):

Counting only states with a probability greater than zero, the total number of combinations is calculated without regard for the underlying distribution.